# Let $ \beta$ be a nonzero element of $ V $ such that $ T \alpha = \beta $. Show that $ \alpha \ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V $ be a vector space over the field $ F $, and let $ T $ be an operator on $ V $. If $ \beta $ is a nonzero element of $ V $ such that $ T \alpha = \beta $, show that $ \alpha \ne  0$.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks for everything.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thus far, you are assuming $\alpha\ne 0$. It is worth closely checking your problem statement and providing any ideas you have in an edit to this question.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is non-zero then $\alpha\neq 0$. Perhaps you meant $\beta \neq 0$?

Comment: @copper.hat   Sorry a little mistake :S

Comment: Hint: a linear map takes $0$ to $0$.

Comment: What **must** $T0$ be?

Comment: An operator need not have any special properties, but I expect that $T$ is a *linear* operator, which is very important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a property of linear transformations $T$ that $T(0)=0$ so if $\alpha =0$ but $T(\alpha)=\beta\ne0$, then $T$ will not be a linear transformation.

**Hint:**

If T is a linear transformation, then
$$T(0+0+\dots+0)=T(0) \to T(0)=0.$$

Comment: thank you for you edit Dear Andres